# Is it true/make sense that Job was given ordeal because he was an overly worried man?

Tags: job

A friend of mine mentioned that the reason Job, the man of righteousness and praised by God, have to go through the ordeal, aside from satan's request to tempt him, was because he's overly worried? In Job 1:5, it's shown that after his kids had parties, Job always went out to offer prayer on behalf of his kids, because he's worried his kids had a slip of tongue and curses God unconsciously while partying.

Comment: I believe Job's care regarding his children is given as an example of his piety, his righteousness.  It was this righteousness that Satan used, through Job's friends, to tempt him into justifying himself rather than God, at which point God stepped in and rescued Job through direct confrontation.

Comment: The entire book of Job is self explanatory and as it unfolds we see the deep reasons within Job which prompted the events of which we read. To say it regards 'over-worrying' would be merely an opinion and I suggest a rather superficial one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***The short answer to your question is No.***

Yes, Job worried that his children might sin when they went out partying and having a good time.  What parent doesn’t worry about what their children might get up to when they are exposed to risk?  Job was not “overly worried”.   He was sensitive to sin and did whatever he could to ensure his children were brought up properly in the fear of the Lord.  That is why Job took steps to purify them after they had feasted.

God knew that his servant Job was blameless and upright, that he had a healthy respect and fear of his creator and he was a man who shunned evil (Job 1:8).  Satan accused God of protecting Job and blessing him with what we might call preferential treatment.  He challenged God by suggesting Job only obeyed God for the rewards (Job 1:9-11).

Satan, the accuser, is granted permission by God to afflict Job, only he must not take his life.  This proves that Satan is under God’s power.  There is a contest going on here – will Job curse God to his faith, or will the accuser be proven false and God vindicated?

It is after Satan afflicts Job that he experiences turmoil and disquiet, that his worst fears are realised.  No amount of justification will avail and Job is forced to confess that he is in error and he repents in dust and ashes (Job 42:1-6).

One possible outcome from God allowing Satan to try and break Job was in order to expose Satan’s evil intent and turn it to good.  We have an example of this when Joseph’s brothers sold him into slavery.  At the end of the day, when Joseph was able to save his people from famine, he could say to his brothers:

> You intended to harm me, but God intended it for good to accomplish what is now being done, the saving of many lives (Genesis 50:19-20).

God uses the example of Job to show that He will sometimes allow people to suffer even when they have done nothing specifically wrong to “deserve” the suffering. Sometimes, suffering is part of God’s plan to purify and mature us.  Job’s life is an example of how to endure suffering patiently:

> As you know, we count as blessed those who have persevered. You have heard of Job’s perseverance and have seen what the Lord finally brought about. The Lord is full of compassion and mercy (James 5:11).

In the end, God’s wager with Satan actually achieved an incredible coup: He harnessed evil and turned it to good and He transformed Job into the most effective servant of all, one who took on God’s own redemptive character and loved his enemies.  There is a powerful lesson there for us.

Answer (score 0):

We don't really know why God did what He did...that's kind of the whole point of Job. God simply wanted Job to trust Him.